# Restart App programmatically when Switch is Pressed

Tags: java, android

I would like to restart the app whenever the switch is pressed, regardless of its current position. However, the issue is that the app restarts even when I navigate to the fragment containing the switch. I specifically want the restart to occur only when the switch is clicked. Here's what I have attempted so far:

```
 nsfwSetting.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {


            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPrefs_nsfw_settings.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(REWARD_GRANTED_KEY, isChecked);
                editor.apply();
                restartMainActivity()
            }
        });
        nsfwSetting.setChecked(mSharedPrefs_nsfw_settings.getBoolean(REWARD_GRANTED_KEY, false));

 private void restartMainActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(requireActivity(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        requireActivity().finish();
    }
```

Could you please assist me in achieving the desired behavior where the app restarts only upon clicking the switch?

Comment: Either 1. initialize the switch state before setting onCheckedChangeListener, or 2. use onClickListener instead.

Comment: i forget about the onClickListner that also works on swtich , thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Switch;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Switch restartSwitch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        restartSwitch = findViewById(R.id.restartSwitch);

        restartSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (restartSwitch.isChecked()) {
                    restartApp();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void restartApp() {
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getPackageName());
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```